# Custom procedure for sorting an array

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Im going through one of my old exam papers, preparing for my finals, and for the love of life, I cant figure out how to do this!
The program was working earlier, but it wasn't sorting the array. Now Im getting an error saying `EAccess violation with message: access violation at address 00404BDE`

Here's my code (its kind of long, maybe you can help me spot my error) :

```
private

    { Private declarations }
    iCount : Integer;
    arrDams : array [1..200] of string;
    Procedure List;
    procedure Display;
    procedure Sort;
    procedure Search (sDam : String);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Display;  //Display with Numbers
var
  k : Integer;
begin
  for K := 1 to 200 do
    begin
      RedOut.Lines.Add (IntToStr(k) + '.) ' + (arrDams[k]));
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); // Create
begin
//
end;

procedure TForm1.List; // TextFile to array
var
  MyFile : TextFile;
  k : Integer;
begin
  If FileExists('Dams.txt') <> True
    then Application.Terminate;

  AssignFile (MyFile, 'Dams.txt');
  Reset(MyFile);
  For K := 1 to 200 do
    begin
      Readln(MyFile, arrDams[k])
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Search(sDam: String); // Search
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.Sort; // Sort;
var
  K,L : byte;
  sKeep : string;
begin
  for k := 1 to iCount -1 do
    begin
      for l := k + 1 to iCount do
        begin
          if arrDams[k] > arrDams[L] then
            begin
              sKeep := arrDams[k];
              arrDams[k] := arrDams[L];
              arrDams[L] := sKeep
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnListClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 List;
 Display;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  display;
  sort;
end; //<---------- ERROR OVER HERE!

end.
```

Theres 3 buttons at the top of the form, namely `Show list`, `Make new textfile with list` and `Sort list alphabetically`. The button Im working on is to sort the list. This question paper says I must make a `sort procedure` and must be called when the `Sort Button` is clicked.

Thanks for any advice/help

P.S.

Can you please point me to a link where they explain Selection Sorting in depth - the logic isn't with me on this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize `iCount`. So it is 0. Therefore `iCount-1` is `-1`. However, you use `Byte`, an unsigned type, for your loop variable. Now, `-1` when interpreted as an unsigned `Byte` is `255`. If you follow this all through it means that you access the array out of bounds. In fact what happens is that the inner loop executes exactly once with a value of `l` equal to `0` and `k` equal to `255`.

Were you to enable the range checking compiler option, you would have encountered a runtime error as soon as you run off the end of the array.

Presumably you want to initialize `iCount` to some value. I cannot tell what, but you will know.

Beyond that, stop using unsigned types for loop variables. Replace `Byte` with `Integer`.

Comment: ...also, *turn on range checking!*  That said, I don't think this will even index the array out of bounds, purely by luck.  The inner loop runs from `k + 1 to iCount`, which simply doesn't run at all when `iCount` is zero.  I think OP has redacted the actual offending code.

Comment: Thank you. I followed my text book's instructions, but it isn't very clear.

Comment: @J... This one is the problem: `for k := 1 to iCount -1 do` because it runs from 1 to 255 when `iCount` is `0`. Then when `k` is 255 the inner loop fires a single time with `l` equal to `0`. Try this program to see what I mean: `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  k, l: Byte;
  iCount: Integer;

begin
  for k := 1 to iCount -1 do
    for l := k + 1 to iCount do
      Writeln(l, ' ', k);
end.`

Comment: Ah, right... the wraparound kick from behind, missed that.